# Rails, using whenever gem in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, whenever

Sorry quick question here from a relative Rails newbie. I'm trying to use the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to schedule a number of rake tasks.  I can't for the life of me get it to actually begin running the cron jobs on my development machine.

Judging from other stackoverflow threads, it appears I should add this:

```
set :environment, "development"
```

to my schedule.rb file.  But then what?

And then how do I stop the cron jobs once they've started?

Using Rails 3.2.3 in OSX

UPDATE: the answer is to run `$ whenever -w` which writes the cron job to a crontab file. The system then immediately starts running that crontab file automatically.

Unfortunately, my logfile for whenever contains the following: 
`"rake aborted! Don't know how to build task <task name>"`

I'm thinking this might be due to the known crontab/rvm issue, but any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 80):

Clear existing cron jobs.

```
crontab -r
```

Update cronjob with the environment.

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

Comment: I would like to see a more informative description of exactly what these commands do, aimed at a beginner!

Comment: "crontab -r" Clear all current cron jobs
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `whenever` command and its various options to manipulate your crontab.

```
$ whenever --help
Usage: whenever [options]
    -i [identifier],                 Default: full path to schedule.rb file
        --update-crontab
    -w, --write-crontab [identifier] Default: full path to schedule.rb file
    -c, --clear-crontab [identifier]
    -s, --set [variables]            Example: --set 'environment=staging&path=/my/sweet/path'
    -f, --load-file [schedule file]  Default: config/schedule.rb
    -u, --user [user]                Default: current user
    -k, --cut [lines]                Cut lines from the top of the cronfile
    -v, --version
```

Comment: Thanks. What I didn't realize was that once you write to the crontab file using `whenever -w`, the crontab start running automatically (i.e. you don't have to do anything else to execute it.) Unfortunately, my logfile for whenever says "rake aborted! Don't know how to build task <task name>"  The rake task works on its own just using $ rake from the command prompt. Any suggestions?

Comment: You probably have incorrect syntax somewhere in the task or whenever event. Try to get a more informative stack trace.

Comment: Doing some searching around, it appears this may be an issue with RVM, which apparently has some problems with Whenever.  Any suggestions on this would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
whenever -c cron-name  #removing cronjobs
```

Answer (score -2):

Adding following line of code on top of config/schedule.rb worked for me.

```
 ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "development"
```