# Whenever gem for cron in Rails can not be running in Mac and can't found the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rubygems, whenever

in my `config/schedule.rb`:

```
set :environment, "development"
set :output, "log/cron.log"

every 2.minutes do
  rake "reset_expired_pin:generate"
end
```

then i run `whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'` then `crontab -l` i see the cron in that list 
and after I refresh my DB every 2 mins, it doesn't update anything ( my rake command not run ),
I have a search on this issue on this StackOverflow and do what the answers said, but doesn't work so i finally ask here to get help,
is `wheneever gem` not support on OSX ? and can't be running in development mode ??
i also can't found the log file of that cron , i thought it gonna saved in my rails app root, but it doesn't, i follow [this intructions to get log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612818/whenever-gem-i-set-output-but-the-logfile-doesnt-show-up-where-id-expect-it), and i [follow this instructions](https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/04/ruby-whenever-gem/) for run whenever
but nothing lucking to find this log in my Mac

`crontab -l`:

```
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/me/Documents/myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2020-05-16 07:12:15 +0800
0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,30,32,34,36,38,40,42,44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 
'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd /Users/me/Documents/myapp && RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake reset_expired_pin:generate --silent >> log/cron.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/me/Documents/myapp/config/schedule.rb at: 2020-05-16 07:12:15 +0800
```

Comment: Plenty of things could be wrong. Check to make sure your cron daemon is running? Can it run regular jobs like `echo test > /tmp/test`? If not, then your cron daemon isn't working. If it does work, then look for your cron daemon logs (nothing to do with ruby or gem).

Comment: Can you show the resulting `crontab` that was generated?

Comment: @StephenCrosby how to check it

Comment: @tadman just updated the log of it above

Comment: That indicates where the log should be. What's in it? Do you have a `/Users/me/Documents/myapp/log` directory?

Comment: ohh yes it is there, but i got error: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/bundler_version_finder.rb:80:in `pwd': Operation not permitted - getcwd (Errno::EPERM)` , i think i am using 2.7.1 by rbenv , but i dont know why they use 2.6

Comment: also it said ~/myapp/.ruby-version: Operation not permitted @tadman

Comment: That's a permission problem of some kind. Looks like rbenv isn't loading in your cron environment.

Comment: i saw whenever wiki said i should put this `set :rbenv_root, '/opt/rbenv'` but when i search /opt/rbenv on my local , not found, how to know the root rbenv ?? @tadman

Comment: i found it by called ''~/.rbenv" but still got that error ~/myapp/.ruby-version: Operation not permitted  @tadman

Comment: just found out it @tadman

Answer (score 4):

i found it just now, been find out this problem since yesterday and found out just now,
to resolve it, we should set up the env of RBENV if you are using RBENV and set the version of ruby and it gonna find the ruby-version in your root file app rail
i set it up it

```
set :rbenv_root, '~/.rbenv'
set :rbenv_version, '2.7.1'
env 'RBENV_ROOT', rbenv_root
env 'RBENV_VERSION', rbenv_version
job_type :rake, 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output'
set :environment, "development"
```

env of RBENV must on the top 
and on that `job_type:`
we set it up for get the PATH of rbenv because it gonna run by bash

one thing is more importan the ~/Libary on Mac must be executable, so we could it set up for cron follow this : 
https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/

Comment: `job_type :rake, 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; cd :path && :environment_variable=:environment bundle exec rake :task --silent :output'` made my day!