# Rails Whenever set environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, whenever

I'm using whenever to generate the cronjobs for my Rails application.
Rails 4.2.1

In the schedule.rb I have something like that:

```
every 13.minutes do
   rake "crons:dosomething"
end
```

This generates a cronjoblike this:

```
 RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake crons:dosomething
```

Problem is that this one only runs cronjobs for production environment ... but I need the cronjob as well in test and development

I tried this:

```
every 13.minutes do
   rake "crons:dosomething", :environment => :development
   rake "crons:dosomething", :environment => :test
   rake "crons:dosomething", :environment => :production
end
```

problem here is that the second rake runs before the first one is completely finished is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514968/rails-using-whenever-gem-in-development