# Cron job doesn't work with whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I want to create a schedule cron job.
I used whenever. My rails version is 4.1.6 and I am in osx.

So I created a schedule cron job to test.

schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
    runner "DatabaseWatcher.run"
end
```

patch:

```
/lib/DatabaseWatcher.rb
```

class:

```
class DatabaseWatcher
        def run
            puts "test"
        end
     end
```

After this I did:

$ whenever

```
## [message] Above is your schedule file converted to cron syntax; your crontab file was not updated.
## [message] Run `whenever --help' for more options.
```

$ whenever -w

```
[write] crontab file written
```

I never saw "test" in my command-line.
What I did wrong?

Comment: It's not run through your terminal session, so it's not output there.

Comment: Update your question with the output from `crontab -l`

Comment: # Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/diogo/MIT/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'ls'


# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/diogo/MIT/config/schedule.rb

Comment: crontab doesnt have your task in it therefore i wont run, you need to figure out why its not writing to crontab

Comment: @Zahid wrong paste. This is the last version:
# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/diogo/MIT/config/schedule.rb
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/diogofrazao/MIT && bin/rails runner -e production '\''DatabaseWatcher.run'\'''


# End Whenever generated tasks for: /Users/diogo/MIT/config/schedule.rb

Comment: Put this in your schedule.rb: `set :output, "log/cron_log.log"`.  Then you'll have a log file with your error message.  MABW has the reason below.

Answer (score 1):

I have already got this error before.
Add class method in your run method using `.self`. If DatabaseWatcher in `/lib/DatabaseWatcher.rb` didn't called you have to move into folder app/models/database_watcher.rb

```
class DatabaseWatcher
  def self.run
    puts "test"
  end
end
```

This is to update your crontab in environment development.

```
# to update crontab
whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development
# show crontab list
crontab -l
```

For references :

1. [rails-using-whenever-gem-in-development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514968/rails-using-whenever-gem-in-development)

Comment: What he said.  Try running your command from the rails console: `DatabaseWatcher.run`.  It will give an error.  It's not correct ruby syntax.  You need to make a it a class method.