# Whenever Gem Daily email using actionmailer not sending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, whenever

I can't seem to make the whenever gem work with my actionmailer. I am trying to run the application in development wherein an email would be sent to a specific individual at a specific time.

In my schedule.rb file I have the following:

```
every :day, :at => '12:48pm' do
  runner "FoodPlan.food_email"
end
```

In my controller called food_plans_controller.rb I have:

```
  def self.food_email
    @food_plans = FoodPlan.where(food_plan_date: Date.today).order('meal ASC')

    UserMailer.food_email(@food_plans).deliver_now
  end
```

In user_mailer.rb I have (take note I removed the email for privacy reasons) :

```
  def food_email (food)
    @food_plans = food

    mail(to: '---------@yahoo.com', subject: 'Food Orders for #{Date.today}')
  end
```

I have a folder in the views called user_mailer, inside it is a file called food_email.html.erb with the ff:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
</head>
  <body>
    <h1>title</h1>
    <p>
      Good morning, -----!
      <br><br>
      Meal Plans for <%=Date.today%>:
      <br><br>
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Meal Plan</th>
      <th>Ordered by</th>
      <th>Room Number</th>
      <th>Received by</th>
      <th>Signature</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <%countint=1%>
    <% @food_plans.each do |food_plan| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%=countint%></td>
        <td><%= food_plan.meal %></td>
        <td><%=food_plan.applicant.first_name%>
        <%=food_plan.applicant.last_name%></td>
        <td><%=food_plan.applicant.room_number%></td>
        <%countint+=1%>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>


  </tbody>
</table>
      <br>
      <br>
      ---.
      <br>
      <br>
      If you have any concerns, don't hesitate to call us at ------.

      <br>
      <br>
      Thanks, <br>----
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my development config I have (I removed the email and password):

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '-------',
  password:             '-------',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

I have tried reading this [guide](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/whenever-gem/Ima-tvdqZds/Y30xMxp1sGgJ) but I cannot still get the gem to work with actionmailer. I have also read up on the [documentation](https://github.com/javan/whenever) of the whenever gem but I still can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. :(

I'm not getting any errors, it's just that the email is not sending.

Comment: Specifically what doesn't work and what issue are you having? Are you getting an error? Is the mail not being sent even though you expect it to?

Comment: The email is not being sent. I don't think that it's even going into the scheduler. I'm looking at the logs of my localhost terminal and there aren't any changes to the logs even during the time I specified in the scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your whenever rules did not ever get to the local `crontab` and thus are never actually run. The whenever gem rules do not make the system run the commands by theselves, they are only a **ruby notation of the [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) rules** that reside in the `/etc/crontab` (or similar) on unix-like systems.

The whenever gem automatically updates the `crontab` during deployment (using the [capistrano plugin](https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration)), so your rules should work on the production server.

On the development host however, you need to update your `crontab` manually ([credits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087812/1544012)):

```
whenever --update-crontab --set environment='development'
```

To view what's currently inside your `crontab`, use `cat /etc/crontab`. Your rules, defined in whenever, should be present in the file after you've updated it.