# Whenever gem with cron or Resque gem for running tasks in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, jobs

I have a stock portfolio app that gets financial data from Yahoo Finance. I want to set up a feature that will calculate the portfolio's value (which will involve sending a get request to yahoo for all of the relevant stock prices and calculating the price * quantity and save that in the amount attribute of a portfolio object). I have a valuation model (that belongs_to a portfolio) that will be used to create valuation instances that will store the portfolio amount and date every day. I will then plot the portfolio's valuations on a graph to track the performance of it's stock picks.

I only want to run this once a day at the end of the day. As it stands now, I am thinking of simply using the whenever gem to schedule a task and run the above actions to fetch and calculate prices. Could this be a good use case for a background processing framework like Resque?

Comment: u can use this answer for reference
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994581/rails-5-scheduler-to-update-database-once-a-day/40995192#40995192

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to complete your task. One of the way is to write rake task and run them once per day. For scheduling you can use `whenever` gem. It provides convenience way to describe cron schedule.

Whenever docs:

> Whenever is a Ruby gem that provides a clear syntax for writing and
>   deploying cron jobs.

```
# We will run rake task every day at some time
every :day, :at => '12:20am' do
  rake 'calculate_averages'
end
```

Example of task:

```
require 'rake'

task :calculate_averages => :environment do
  products = Product.all

  products.each do |product|
    puts "Calculating average rating for #{product.name}..."
    product.update_attribute(:average_rating, product.reviews.average("rating"))
  end
end
```

To start read [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) docs and how to write [rake tasks.](https://richonrails.com/articles/building-a-simple-rake-task) How to write [tasks #2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).